# Where put batch process in a joomla

Tags: joomla, batch-processing

I have a Joomla website and I have to make a Batch process to run every day at midnight. The thing is that I don't know where I should put the process. I thought I'd make a new component but it isn't a component.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use a CRON job, or check the [Joomla Extensions Directory](http://extensions.joomla.org) for something that might be helpful.  To my knowledge processing on Joomla depends on a user displaying a page for anything to be triggered for execution

Answer (score 0):

If it's Joomla 2.5+ you can use `cron` to trigger a Joomla platform app - like the ones you find in the `/cli/` directory.

Lots of extensions do it, the most famous one is probably [Akeeba Backup](https://www.akeebabackup.com/documentation/akeeba-backup-documentation/native-cron-script.html).